# Generate empty workspace with Angular CLI v6

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is it possible to generate an empty workspace with Angular CLI v6? It may contain an initial app but within the default `projects` folder.

Comment: Have you tried `ng new yourApp` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update: Angular 7**

It is now possible to create an empty workspace with the following command:

`ng new --createApplication false`

---

Currently you can not but hopefully this feature will be availiable soon.

You can track related issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10709

Answer (score 0):

BTW, with Angular 16, you need to use following command to create an empty workspace without an initial app:

```
ng new MyWorkspace --no-create-application
```

[see angular doc on new command](https://angular.io/cli/new)https://angular.io/cli/new